# executing a job containing a rest request from another job in talend

Tags: rest, maven, talend, jobs, esb

So im working with talend esb 8 and i have a job let's call it "restjob" that contains a trestrequest some work and a trestresponse . i want to execute this job in another so i made a new job and i called the "restjob" with the component trunjob .
but i have a probleme when executing the job i have a lot of errors can someone help me maybe i have configured something wrong or something .

the log of errors :

```
    org.talend.designer.runprocess.ProcessorException: java.lang.Exception: [ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[ERROR] Unresolveable build extension: Plugin org.apache.felix:maven-bundle-plugin:5.1.1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:3.3.0, org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-classworlds:jar:1.2-alpha-9: Cannot access central (https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/) in offline mode and the artifact org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:3.3.0 has not been downloaded from it before. @ 
[ERROR] Unknown packaging: bundle @ line 14, column 14
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]   The project org.example.api_discovery.service:create_user:0.1.0 (C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\Studio\workspace\API_DISCOVERY\poms\jobs\process\api_discovery\create_user_0.1\pom.xml) has 2 errors
[ERROR]     Unresolveable build extension: Plugin org.apache.felix:maven-bundle-plugin:5.1.1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:3.3.0, org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-classworlds:jar:1.2-alpha-9: Cannot access central (https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/) in offline mode and the artifact org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:3.3.0 has not been downloaded from it before. -> [Help 2]
[ERROR]     Unknown packaging: bundle @ line 14, column 14
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
[ERROR] [Help 2] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginManagerException

    at org.talend.designer.runprocess.ProcessorUtilities.generateBuildInfo(ProcessorUtilities.java:818)
    at org.talend.designer.runprocess.ProcessorUtilities.generateCode(ProcessorUtilities.java:706)
    at org.talend.designer.runprocess.ProcessorUtilities.generateCode(ProcessorUtilities.java:2029)
    at org.talend.designer.runprocess.RunProcessContext$2.run(RunProcessContext.java:663)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.runInCurrentThread(ModalContext.java:436)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.run(ModalContext.java:352)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.ProgressMonitorDialog.run(ProgressMonitorDialog.java:468)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.progress.ProgressMonitorJobsDialog.run(ProgressMonitorJobsDialog.java:228)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.progress.ProgressManager.run(ProgressManager.java:984)
    at org.talend.designer.runprocess.RunProcessContext.exec(RunProcessContext.java:610)
    at org.talend.designer.runprocess.ui.ProcessComposite.exec(ProcessComposite.java:1447)
    at org.talend.designer.runprocess.ui.views.ProcessView$RunAction.run(ProcessView.java:736)
    at org.talend.designer.runprocess.ui.actions.RunProcessAction.run(RunProcessAction.java:63)
    at org.talend.designer.core.debug.JobLaunchConfigurationDelegate$1$1.run(JobLaunchConfigurationDelegate.java:98)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:40)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4001)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3629)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$5.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1157)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1046)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:155)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:644)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:551)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:156)
    at org.talend.rcp.intro.Application.start(Application.java:303)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:401)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:255)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:654)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:591)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1462)
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: [ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[ERROR] Unresolveable build extension: Plugin org.apache.felix:maven-bundle-plugin:5.1.1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:3.3.0, org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-classworlds:jar:1.2-alpha-9: Cannot access central (https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/) in offline mode and the artifact org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:3.3.0 has not been downloaded from it before. @ 
[ERROR] Unknown packaging: bundle @ line 14, column 14
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]   The project org.example.api_discovery.service:create_user:0.1.0 (C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\Studio\workspace\API_DISCOVERY\poms\jobs\process\api_discovery\create_user_0.1\pom.xml) has 2 errors
[ERROR]     Unresolveable build extension: Plugin org.apache.felix:maven-bundle-plugin:5.1.1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:3.3.0, org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-classworlds:jar:1.2-alpha-9: Cannot access central (https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/) in offline mode and the artifact org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:3.3.0 has not been downloaded from it before. -> [Help 2]
[ERROR]     Unknown packaging: bundle @ line 14, column 14
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
[ERROR] [Help 2] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginManagerException

    at org.talend.designer.maven.launch.MavenCommandLauncher.execute(MavenCommandLauncher.java:401)
    at org.talend.designer.maven.launch.MavenPomCommandLauncher.execute(MavenPomCommandLauncher.java:57)

    at org.talend.designer.maven.tools.BuildCacheManager.build(BuildCacheManager.java:230)
    at org.talend.designer.runprocess.maven.MavenJavaProcessor.build(MavenJavaProcessor.java:422)
    at org.talend.designer.runprocess.ProcessorUtilities.generateBuildInfo(ProcessorUtilities.java:815)
    ... 38 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1- Make sure in maven settings "offline" is unchecked and try again.

2- Have you tried to stop studio -> rename the .m2 folder under your <studio_installation_dir>\configuration -> start studio to regenerate the .m2 folder?

Comment: yess thank you i just needed to uncheck the offline box